# How to check null and apply filter in JPA Querydsl?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, querydsl

I have a scenario like below and i am using JPA Query DSL:

```
List<Student> allStudents(String inputDob){
     List<Student> resultList = jpaQuery.from(student)
                    .where(student.dob.eq(inputDob) //how to skip this condition in case inputdob is null
                    .and(student.age.eq(25)))    
                    .fetch(); 
}
//My question is suppose : inputDob is null then how to skip the where clause if parameter is comming as null?
```

Answer (score 0):

An if/else statement might work for you.

```
List<Student> allStudents(String inputDob){
    List<Student> resultList = null;
    if (inputDob == null || inputDob.isEmpty()) {
         resultList = jpaQuery.from(student)
                .where(student.age.eq(25))
                .fetch();
    } else {
        resultList = jpaQuery.from(student)
                .where(student.dob.eq(inputDob)
                        .and(student.age.eq(25)))
                .fetch();
    }
}
```

You initialize the resultList before the if/else statement, so you can avoid compilation errors later. Then you run the appropriate query, depending on the input.

Please let me know if this was helpful for your case.

Comment: Thanks ,But is there any way to check null with in same line bcoz i have multiple input parameter and with this approch i have to write multiple if else block

Comment: I am sorry, I am not familiar with this framework... I tried to see if I can import it to a project of mine, but IntelliJ IDEA is giving me a hard time... Where do you get the `student` variable from?